# What does this sass statement mean?

Tags: sass

I'm new to sass, could you please explain what the following statement mean?

```
[class*='icon--']::before {
  @mixin icon;
}
```

Doe's it mean; add to **::before** pseudo of all elements with a class, which begins with **icon--** the icon mixin?

The above code is then used like this:

```
[class*='icon--']::before {
  @mixin icon;
}

.icon--bag::before {
  content: '\e602';
}

.icon--book::before {
  content: '\e618';
}
```

Does it mean that the above code will be converted to this?

```
.icon--bag::before {
  @mixin icon;
  content: '\e602';
}

.icon--book::before {
  @mixin icon;
  content: '\e618';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It selects every class that contains the `icon--` string and adds the `icon` mixin to its `before` pseudo element .

So lets say that mixin `icon` looks like

```
@mixin icon {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Then `icon--bag` would be

```
.icon--bag::before {
  display: inline-block; /* from the mixin */
  content: '\e602';
}
```